# Internal Server Error Message in LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

In last few days everyone is facing `Internal server error` on company status update via LinkedIn API ([docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_share)).

Sample response with request Id:

```
 {"requestId":"P8T2EIBBT7","errorCode":0,"message":"Internal service error","status":500,"timestamp":1517889931789}}
 {"requestId":"XNNMPVUFA4","errorCode":0,"message":"Internal service error","status":500,"timestamp":1517877007035}}
```

What could the cause be?